# How to add PHP PEAR SMTP auth into email

Tags: php, html, smtp, pear

I have been working at this for hours and can not figure it out. I am trying to add smtp authentication into sending this email and it does not seem to work. Here is the code that does not have any of the pear php authentication in it.

I have already installed pear mail on my webserver but it still does not work.

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['sendemail']))

{
// Start email send notification
$date = $_POST['date'];
$propertydescription = $_POST['propertydescription'];
$transactiontype = $_POST['transactiontype'];
$received = $_POST['recieved'];
$paid = $_POST['paid'];
$tj = $_POST['tj'];
$agentclientr = $_POST['agentclientr'];
$apdoc =$_POST['apdoc'];

                    $to = "$b5,xxxx@xxxx.net";  
                    $subject = "Automated email from J. xxxxProperties";

                    $message = "
                    <html>
<p>This email serves as confirmation that a new item has recently posted to your account.</p>
<p><a href='http://xxxxxxjlindsey.net/manage</a><br>
  Login: $b3</p>

<table border='0' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='+1' bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
        <tbody>
          <tr bgcolor='#666666'>
            <td><strong><font size='1' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#FFFFFF'>Date</font></strong></td>
            <td><strong><font size='1' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#FFFFFF'>Property/Description</font></strong></td>
            <td><strong><font size='1' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#FFFFFF'>TransactionType</font></strong></td>
            <td><strong><font size='1' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#FFFFFF'>Applicable Document</font></strong></td>
            <td><strong><font size='1' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#FFFFFF'>Received</font></strong></td>
            <td align='right'><strong><font size='1' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#FFFFFF'>Paid</font></strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
            <td><font size='1' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#666666'>$date</font></td>
            <td><font size='1' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#666666'>$propertydescription</font></td>
            <td><font size='1' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#666666'>$transactiontype</font></td>
            <td><font size='1' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#666666'>$apdoc</font></td>
            <td align='right'><font size='1' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#666666'>$received</font></td>
            <td align='right'><font size='1' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='#666666'>$paid</font></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
                    </html>
                    <p><font size='-2' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' color='red'>If this is the first time you've received an automated transmission from us, please send us an <a href='mailto:re@xxxxxx.net?Subject=Received email.'>email</a>.</font>";

                    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
                    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

                    // More headers
                    $headers .= 'From: <noreply@jlindsey.net>' . "\r\n";


                    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "<b><Center>Succesfully sent email to</b> $b5</center>";



                     // End email send notification
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as the question was "How to add PHP PEAR SMTP auth into email", I'll address that
rather than suggest you use something else :)

Because you need to send the HTML as a mime encode email, you also need to use the Mail/mime package that is provided by PEAR so I've included that as well. You may not need
to set the $port value - depending on your mailer setup or whether you might be using gmail behind the scenes.

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "Mail/mime.php";

$from = "<noreply@jlindsey.com>";
$to = "fred@example.com"; // the email address
$host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "587";
// use the first example username if sending from gmail, as full email address 
// is required
$username = "fred.flintstone@gmail.com";
$username = "fred";
$password = "secure";
$headers = array ('From' => $from,'To' => $to,'Subject' => $subject);
$mailbody = "<html><body>...</body></html>";

$mime = new Mail_mime();
$mime->setHTMLBody($mailbody);
$body = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);
$smtp = Mail::factory(
    'smtp',array (
        'host' => $host,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'port' => $port
    )
);

// send email
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo($mail->getMessage());
} else {
    echo "<b><Center>Succesfully sent email to</b>$to</center>";
}
```

Comment: This works for me but I get error messages: Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically and Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically.  which confuse me. Are these not static methods?

Comment: Old answer but saved me day :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)  it will solve your problem. and if you are on linux machine then install postfix for mail server.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'jswan';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```